# Let $\vec{v}=\vec{i}\times (\vec{j}\times (\vec{k}\times (\vec{i}\times ....$

Tags: vectors

Problem :

Let $\vec{v}=\vec{i}\times (\vec{j}\times (\vec{k}\times (\vec{i}\times (\vec{j}\times (\vec{k}\times (\vec{i}\times (\vec{j}\times (\vec{j} \times \vec{k}))))))))$ Then find the value of $||\vec{v}||$

I am not getting any idea how to proceed in this, please suggest , will be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: What are $\vec i$, $\vec j$, and $\vec k$?

Comment: If those are indeed the **unit** basis vectors, have you tried starting with the case of just taking the cross product of two of them at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work from inside to out, starting with $j \times k=i,$ at first glance it seems you'll end up at $\pm$ one of $i,j,k$ so norm is $1.$

Added: The quaternions are a division ring, in particular are associative. Since $ijk=ii=-1,$ the first two of $ijkijkijjk$ make $+1,$ and then $ijjk=-ik=j.$

Comment: Could be $0$ as well.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes might be zero. But seems not as the things repeat in blocks of threes and the innermost isn't zero. I get $-j$ for this.

Comment: A complete answer should warn the OP about this possibility and prove that it doesn't occur. The final vector is $+\vec j$.

Comment: @YvesDaost Note that I worded my answer as "it seems you'll end up at..." making it clear OP should actually do the steps. [and believe it or not I did get $+j$ but miscopied from my paper]

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sorry, misspelled your username in above response to your comment, just now doing another so you get notiied.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$$\vec{i}\times (\vec{j}\times (\vec{k}\times (\vec{i}\times (\vec{j}\times (\vec{k}\times (\vec{i}\times (\vec{j}\times (\vec{j} \times \vec{k}))))))))$$

$$\vec{i}\times (\vec{j}\times (\vec{k}\times (\vec{i}\times (\vec{j}\times (\vec{k}\times (\vec{i}\times (\vec{j}\times \vec{i})))))))$$

$$-\vec{i}\times (\vec{j}\times (\vec{k}\times (\vec{i}\times (\vec{j}\times (\vec{k}\times (\vec{i}\times\vec{k}))))))$$

$$\vec{i}\times (\vec{j}\times (\vec{k}\times (\vec{i}\times (\vec{j}\times (\vec{k}\times \vec{j})))))$$

$$-\vec{i}\times (\vec{j}\times (\vec{k}\times (\vec{i}\times (\vec{j}\times \vec{i}))))$$

$$\vec{i}\times (\vec{j}\times (\vec{k}\times (\vec{i}\times \vec{k})))$$

$$-\vec{i}\times (\vec{j}\times (\vec{k}\times \vec{j}))$$

$$\vec{i}\times (\vec{j}\times \vec i)$$

$$-\vec{i}\times \vec k$$

$$\vec{j}$$

You must check all intermediate results.

Comment: Shameful downvote, this is the only correct answer here.

Comment: OP is asking for $\|v\|$. You might want to take the norm in the very last step?

Comment: @Jack I should flag as a hint as I indeed leave this trivial step to the reader. But those who blindly answered $1$ are right by chance and missed the possibility of a zero.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to be methodical about it.

$$ \begin{align} \vec{v}&=\vec{i}\times(\vec{j}\times(\vec{k}\times(\vec{i}\times(\vec{j}\times(\vec{k}\times(\vec{i}\times(\vec{j}\times(\vec{j}\times\vec{k}))))))))&&\vec{j}\times\vec{k}=\vec{i}\\&=\vec{i}\times(\vec{j}\times(\vec{k}\times(\vec{i}\times(\vec{j}\times(\vec{k}\times(\vec{i}\times(\vec{j}\times\vec{i})))))))&&\vec{j}\times\vec{i}=-\vec{k}\\&=\vec{i}\times(\vec{j}\times(\vec{k}\times(\vec{i}\times(\vec{j}\times(\vec{k}\times(\vec{i}\times(-\vec{k})))))))&&\vec{i}\times\left(-\vec{k}\right)=\vec{j}\\&=\vec{i}\times(\vec{j}\times(\vec{k}\times(\vec{i}\times(\vec{j}\times(\vec{k}\times\vec{j})))))&&\vec{k}\times\vec{j}=-\vec{i}\\&=\vec{i}\times(\vec{j}\times(\vec{k}\times(\vec{i}\times(\vec{j}\times(-\vec{i})))))&&\vec{j}\times\left(-\vec{i}\right)=\vec{k}\\&\vdots&& \end{align} $$

Comment: From my findings, $-\vec i\times\vec k$.

Answer (score -1):

As always, the cross product supplies you with a vector that is orthogonal to both vectors, with a magnitude equal to the parallelogram made by them.

Crossing any of the three unit vectors will give a new positive or negative $i, j, k$. As such, no matter how many you cross, you will always have a unit vector. This has a magnitude of $1$.

Comment: "no matter how many you cross": what about $\vec{i}\times (\vec{j} \times \vec{k})$ ?

Comment: Ah, that's an excellent point, should have considered it. It doesn't happen in this question though.